# iOS error for application

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I'm creating a login and registration for my app. Every time I run this code I recieve this error:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "THRAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([THRAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what it means? I believe its happening from the server side(PHP)

Also the JSON response I keep getting is error: False

Here is the php code:

```
function registerUser($email, $name, $username, $password){

    $uuid               = uniqid('', true);
    $hash               = hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; //encrypted password
    $salt               = $hash["salt"]; //salt password


$register = query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email' limit 1");  

    if (count($register['result'])>0) {

        errorJson('This email is already registered. Try to login or recover your password.');
    }



    //try to register the user

$result  = query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, username, encrypted_password, salt) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email','$username', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");    
    if (!$result['error']) {
        //success
        login($email, $password);

    } else {
        //error
        //errorJson('Sorry, something went wrong :( . Please try again later.');
        errorJson(mysql_error());
    }

}

function login($email, $password){

    $result = query("SELECT uid, email FROM users WHERE email ='%s' AND password ='%s' limit 1", $email, $password);

    if (count($result['result'])>0) {


            $salt               = $result['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
            $hash               = checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);

            //checking for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                //user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
                //authorized
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $result['result'][0]['uid'];

                print json_encode($result);
            }

    } else {
        //not authorized
        errorJson('Wrong Email and password combination.');
    }

}

function hashSSHA($password){

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0,10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

/*
    *Decrypting password
    *#param salt. pasword
    returns hash string
    */
function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password){

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password.$salt, true) . $salt);
        return $hash;
    }
```

Xcode error

```
2012-10-11 15:04:42.528 Thryfting[1457:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1883964'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1752012 0x1577e7e 0x17dd4bd 0x1741bbc 0x174194e 0x6184af 0x618674 0x8b0706 0x8be578 0x8beb50 0x1b5fb 0x1ce4c 0x1e6fb 0xed99 0x1f0753f 0x1f19014 0x1f097d5 0x16f8af5 0x16f7f44 0x16f7e1b 0x2c827e3 0x2c82668 0x4bf65c 0x2bad 0x2ad5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: What code are you running that returns this crash?  What should you be receiving from the PHP server?  Have you ran any breakpoints in your code that may help narrow down where this issue is occurring?

Comment: @Brayden error : false is the JSON response I'm getting

Comment: @DanielA.White I added the php code

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm using mysql_real_escape_string with the query() function I created

Comment: you are processing json response and parsing bool as string, it cause error -> -[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]:. Provide json parser code.

Comment: @NeverBe parse code such as "1" success "0" for error ?

Comment: i think "success" it is boolean, not string. so -> BOOL success = [[dict objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];

Comment: @NeverBe I have that -(BOOL)isAuthorized
{
    return [[user objectForKey:@"uid"] intValue]>0;
}  so I think it maybe be something with my php code

Comment: provide json fragment, it may help

Answer (score 0):

You can trace your code by Zombie objects:

## <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

select the "Diagnostics" tab and click "Enable Zombie Objects":

[image: Click "Enable Zombie Objects"]

This turns released objects into NSZombie instances that print console warnings when used again. This is a debugging aid that increases memory use (no object is really released) but improves error reporting.

A typical case is when you over-release an object and you don't know which one:

- With zombies: `-[UITextView release]: message sent to deallocated instance`
- Without zombies: [image: EXC_BAD_ACCESS]

---

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I see, your error is

```
[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector....
```

This means that, somewhere in your code (can't tell you where, since you dont provide it) you are sending isEqualToString message to an object that is not a NSString.

Could you please make a quick search and see where are you sending that message? It could be that you are reading a boolean value but treating it as a NSString. Please, check your code, and verify that you check the type of data before you send that message.

Please, provide the piece of code where that could happen.